# Akka teskit.spawn to return ActorSystem

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-typed

I'm using AkkaTestFramework with Akka typed, and I cannot find a way to create an ActorSystem mock for one of my typed Actor.

I found this way

```
val pinger: ActorRefTyped[ItAssetRequest] = testKit.spawn(ItAsset(), "itAssetMock")
```

But this `ActorRefTyped` does not contain a `schedule` which I need internally in my class to use `ask pattern`

In my class where I receive this ActorSystem

```
class RegisterConsumerStream(itAsset: ActorSystemTyped[ItAssetRequest]){


  implicit val schedule: typed.Scheduler = itAsset.scheduler


  itAsset ? (ref => ItAssetRequest(connectorState, ref)


}
```

If I pass a `ActorRefTyped[ItAssetRequest]` there's no schedule so I cannot use the ask pattern since it needs the schedule implicit.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an Actor with testKit.spawn method not an ActorSystem. With the Akka TestKit you already have available an ActorSystem inside your tests:

```
class AgentSpec extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit { 

  val testKitScheduler : Scheduler = system.scheduler 

}
```

With the spawn method from the testKit you create an actor for testing your behaviors not an actor system.

```
class RegisterConsumerStream(as: ActorSystem[Nothing]){

  import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AskPattern._
  implicit val scheduler = as.scheduler

  val ref: ActorRef[ItAssetRequest] = ???
  ref.ask(ref => ItAssetRequest())

}
```

Comment: But with Akka typed you Actor is actually an ActorSystem. And I need to defined the actor as ActorSystem in order to use the schedule of him inside another class which is not an actor

Comment: check the code, this is the ActorSystem implementation

Comment: abstract class ActorSystem[-T]() extends scala.AnyRef with akka.actor.typed.ActorRef[T] with akka.actor.typed.Extensions with akka.actor.ClassicActorSystemProvider {

Comment: as you can see is an ActorRef[T]

Comment: ActorSystem extends from ActorRef, but that does not imply an actor is an actor system. A system also implements the ActorRef type, and sending a message to the system directs that message to the root Actor.

Comment: Try to reproduce this example without define the Actor as actor system. Trying to make ask call to this actor outside an ActorSystem https://github.com/politrons/Akka/blob/master/AkkaTyped/src/main/scala/com/akkaTyped/AkkaTypedFromOutsideActor.scala

Comment: In that example typedActor is an ActorSystem with a root actor with the behavior Behavior[TypedActorMessage]. Unlike classic actor systems in Akka typed an ActorSystem requires the guardian´s behavior: "One difference is that when creating an ActorSystem in Typed you give it a Behavior that will be used as the top level actor, also known as the user guardian"

Comment: I think that you could use the system from Akka teskit for the ask operation.

Comment: I do the ask operation not in my test but in the class that receive the ActorSystem

Comment: you can pass that system as an implicit parameter too

Comment: Yeah but is hard to believe that AkkaTestKit it's not covering this use case. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: I have updated the answer including the code that can help.

Comment: Ok you're now exactly in my situation, but how I can create the ActorSystem actor from the test?, that's the question that I was asking in first place :)

Comment: As I said, there is a system already define when you extends your test class from ScalaTestWithActorTestKit, you can use that when you build your RegisterConsumerStream